# fixing just ownership when forgetting cp -rp

Tags: permissions, file-copy

I have a `/data` folder that has a gazillion files and folders, took all night to copy.

I copied it as root via `cp -r /data/*  /data2`  forgetting the `p`

All my stuff at the destination is owned by root.

I have not deleted the source `/data` but I do not want to recopy if I do not have to.

Is there a way to copy just the permissions, or sync the permissions, between source and destination?

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39573065/540696) answer helpful. `find` could be slow in traversing the directory tree but I did come up with an `rsync` answer.

Comment: You can change ownership & permissions of data partitions, but do not run on any system partitions or you totally break system. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/data` Note -R is recursion so all underlying folders also changed. `sudo chmod -R a+rwX /mnt/data` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: @oldfred This will reset the ownership the files but the OP was also asking about permissions. You need to incorporate a `chmod` somewhere in here.

Comment: I updated the title, I meant to say ownership regarding just uid and gid, I didn't have a problem with the `-rw-r--r--` permission part.

Comment: but ultimately i want the owner.group, and permissions, on the destination to match what  the source was; my observation was the permissions were the same everything got turned into `root.root` ownership which was my problem

Comment: Is $USER not your user & group? `echo $USER` Of if you have multiple users, it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

`mtree` can do this, and offers the advantage that it doesn't need to read the file contents at all.  It compares only the file metadata, and modifies the destination to match the source:

```
$ sudo mtree -cp /data | sudo mtree -Utp /data2
```

`-c` tells the LHS `mtree` to create a heirarchy spec, rooted in the `-p` path of `/data`, and the RHS `mtree` invocation updates the owner/group/perms `-U` and modification times `-t` of the heirarchy rooted in `-p /data2`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `rsync`:

```
rsync -avic --progress /data/ /data2
```

Note:
The trailing `/` on `/data/` is deliberate, it ensures `rsync` will not create `/data2/data` and re-copy all your files under it.  (you don't need a trailing `/` on `/data2`)

The options are:
`-a` which is named for "archive" but really turns on a bunch of useful options (like recursive descent into subdirs) that will imitate your `cp -r` command's behavior.
`-v` and `-i` make the copy verbose and show how `rsync` sets the permissions and ownership on the copied files, which is useful as the copy goes forward.
`-c` uses checksums to decide whether the data in each file should be copied.  This will let `rsync` skip copying the file contents and only adjust the ownership/permissions on the destination files.
`--progress` is not required, but shows the progress copying any file contents to the destination.

The `-v` and `-i` options will make at least one line scroll in your terminal window per file.  Omit them if you don't want this.  You can add `-n` (i.e., `-avicn`) if you want rsync to do a verbose dry run that tells you what it would do, but doesn't make changes to the files.  So a dry run with the `-avicn --progress` options, followed by the real thing with just the `-ac --progress` options may be more desirable for you.

Comment: This is a better answer than the `find` I suggested in my comment.

Comment: The `-c` flag will recalculate checksums for every single file. At that point you might as well just recopy the files - it would be faster for sure

Comment: @roaima that depends.  re-copying the files involves reading and writing all the data bytes.  `rsync -c` involves 2x the reads, but writes can be heaver and slower than reads.